# Button clears other input fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web page am having some dropdown lists. OnSelectedIndexChanged of ddl1 I am binding dropdown lists ddl2 and ddl3 . Once I click the button, ddl2 and ddl3 values clearing.
This happens during postback of Button1. The postback of button1 fires ddl1 OnSelectedIndexChanged event.
Am using Dotnet framework 2.0

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    widestData = 0; 
    lblPCno.Visible = false; 
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
        FillCombos(); 
        BindCoverGridview(); 
    }
}

protected void OnBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillCoverDtls(vShowroom, vCategory,vsubCategory.ToString(),vFamily.ToString()); 
    lblCount.Text = "Total : " + grdCoverDetails.Rows.Count.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Please post code of page_load and button1 click handler

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You ask questions, we answer them. The defining characteristic of a question is that it ends with a question mark ('?', ASCII code 0x3F, on most keyboards it can be found right next to the right shift key.)

Comment: <code> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        widestData = 0;
        lblPCno.Visible = false;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {            
            FillCombos();
            BindCoverGridview();
            
        } <code>
And button click handler is
<code>FillCoverDtls(vShowroom, vCategory,vsubCategory.ToString(),vFamily.ToString());
lblCount.Text = "Total : " + grdCoverDetails.Rows.Count.ToString();
 <code>

Comment: I added your code to the question. It's more readable. Can you post more code, because we can still not see why the textboxes should be cleared. Have you turned off ViewState?

Comment: Thanks for editing. Am not using Viewstate here. The selected index property resets to its initial stage. 
in _page_load_ i dont have any other code. For button click am just calling a function _FillCoverDtls_ which calls a webservice to get data from oracle db and binding into a gridview. 
`$ grdCoverDetails.DataSource = CoverDT;
  grdCoverDetails.DataBind();` 
No there codes are given. To check I cleared every other codes and tried with few lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you turned off ViewState, your textboxes will always be empty after a postback unless you initialize them again.